# Uploadify in ie9 getting js error : SCRIPT5007: Object expected

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, uploadify

I am trying to bind uploadify on div.
When I clicked on upload button it show me error like `SCRIPT5007: Object expected.`

For demo check below link which produced error on dragging of div in ie9

**head**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.uploadify.com/wp-content/themes/uploadify/js/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
```

**body**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div id="uploadify-item"></div>
    This container is not draggable in IE9 but it works in Chrome and FF. Why not?
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#uploadify-item').uploadify({
    'swf'      : 'http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : 'http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.php'
});
$("#container").draggable();
```

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/axzdR/19/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IE9 seems to have a bug with SWFUpload embeds, whereby if you try to
call "getAttribute / removeAttribute / setAttribute" on the element,
an "object expected" error is raised. And I found that the cleanUp()
function in the swfupload.js remove all the js functions including
"getAttribute / removeAttribute / setAttribute" from the object DOM in
IE9.

To fix this issue

In SWFUpload.prototype.cleanUp

Change:

```
if (typeof (movieElement[key]) === "function")
```

To:

```
if (typeof (movieElement[key]) === "function" && key[0] <= 'Z') // Remove only Flash functions (starts with capital letters).
```

Patched version of uploadify is kept at this location

http://www.dariowiz.com/scripts/jquery.uploadify3.1Fixed.js

Regards.

Comment: wow , its works like a charm.I think you have badge of 'Sir' for this.

Comment: @eHussain If I could give you a kiss, I would. I've been struggling with uploadify for two days trying to find a mistake in a large pluggin thinking that it was me who was missing something, browsing internet forums up and down to find no solution. Not until now. THANKS A LOT.
It wouldn't hurt if the fix were incorporated in the production version of the plugin but anyway, it works for me now.

Comment: NOTE: The code change proposed here does fix the problem for me -- BUT the link which indicates that it points at a 'patched' version of Uploadify does not seem to contain the proposed change.  I still had to make the mod.

Comment: Fixed for me with a dynamically added uploadify onto a page which was breaking in IE. Big thanks @eHussain ! Link is broken though. I also updated the version of swf upload from here: https://github.com/WordPress/secure-swfupload

Comment: Patch not available :(

Answer (score 2):

Try using lates jQuery (container is draggable in IE9, and "Object expected" error disapears)

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you have installed Flash player for IE (it is separate install)
It can be downloaded from here
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

But even Unloadify [demos](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) is not working in my IE9 (I can click like a minute in Select files button with no result and suddenly with no reason it starts to work and opens select files dialog)

Comment: in my project , i have to stick with my old  jquery and UI version.

Answer (score 1):

You find the finally solution for this problem here >>> **https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/swfupload/57ySk2JoLbE**

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a problem in the sources of uploadify that conflicts with jquery UI in IE 9. Specifically in the swfupload utility. In order to fix it you need to do a little hack which appears to have detailed steps here: http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/comment/19212

Sorry I can't validate this without setting up a whole test environment. Not something that can just be put in a JSFiddle. Good luck, let me know if you succeed.