# uploadify IE fail on button hover: SCRIPT5007: Object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, uploadify

I'm using uploadify v3.2.1 with jQuery 1.91.

Uploadify is failing to open a dialog box for an upload on IE 9 - 11, but works fine in other browsers. In fact, I get an error message when I hover over the upload button:

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected jquery-1.9.1.js, line 2370 character 5
```

I've tried a couple of solutions I've seen, including [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145365/uploadify-in-ie9-getting-js-error-script5007-object-expected), but there's no change in the functionality. I've even upgraded my version of uploadify, again with no affect.

I've also just realized in my frustration that in IE when I double click the upload button, it does actually work. I don't get it, have no idea what's going on, but need this to work on single click.

I don't know if this helps any, but here is the script:

```
        $("#p_image_upload").uploadify({
              "debug"    : false,
              "formData"      : {"type": "primary"},
               "fileTypeExts" : "*.jpg",
               "swf"      : "uploadify/uploadify.swf",
               "buttonText" : "Upload Primary",
                "fileSizeLimit" : "4MB",
                "multi"    : false,
                 "removeTimeout" : 3,
                "onQueueComplete" : function(queueData) {
                        notify("Your image has been uploaded.",5000);
                        $(".p_logo_show").animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 500,function(){
                        var cli = $("#client_id").val();
                        $(".p_logo_show").attr("src","/img/logos/"+cli+"_primary.jpg").animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
                    })
                },
               "uploader" : "uploadify/uploadify.php?cli="+cli
            });
```

Comment: Can you show the whole page? Is your script in a DOM ready event? What version of Uploadify are you using?

Comment: Solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145365/uploadify-in-ie9-getting-js-error-script5007-object-expected?lq=1